# How to display LinkedIn Sign In button?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to build a LinkedIn login on my ([Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)) website. For this I'm following the steps I found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

I followed the steps 1 to 4, but from there I'm a bit stuck. I currently have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: "7762qdzr8qe7db";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sign In with LinkedIn</h1>
<script type="in/Login">
    Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Supposedly this should show `Sign In with LinkedIn` button, but I see absolutely nothing. I'm running this on localhost (url being `http://127.0.0.1:5000/linkedin`), but according to [the same page I linked at the top](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api), during development that shouldn't be a problem ("*During development, 'localhost' works!*").

In the screenshots below you'll see that I correctly copy-pasted the API key in the js above:

[image]

and even though I use localhost, below you'll see I correctly listed my domain with port 5000 (I also tried without a port):

[image]

I also tried putting this html on my TLD, but also to no avail (plus I guess it should work on localhost too). Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
The problem turned out to be threefold. I needed to

1. add `http://localhost` to the comma separated list of JavaScript API Domains on linkedin.com/secure/developer
2. visit `http://localhost:5000` instead of `127.0.0.1:5000`
3. remove the quotes and semicolon so that the line reads `api_key: 7762qdzr8qe7db`

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have you tried with localhost instead of the ip? Also can you open the console and see if any error is reported there?

Comment: in `api_key: ` line, could the ending semicolon be any problem?

Comment: I got this error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.

Comment: Did you set the javascript api domain to http://localhost?

Comment: @sudo.ie I also tried visiting http://localhost:5000/linkedin (to no avail). I now also get the error saying that I need to specify a valid Javascript API domain now (which is more than I got before.. :)  ). But as you can see from the screenshot, I already included a domain (I now took the `:5000` away), but it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is threefold. You need to

1. add `http://localhost` to the comma separated list of JavaScript API Domains on linkedin.com/secure/developer
2. visit `http://localhost:5000` instead of `127.0.0.1:5000`
3. remove the quotes and semicolon so that the scripts looks as follows

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
       api_key: 7762qdzr8qe7db
   </script>`

Comment: Why the downvotes??? This is how it's specified in the example code http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_login_reg/example.html

Comment: <s>This indeed works now, but it wasn't the solution. The solution was that I needed to add `localhost` to the comma separated list of JavaScript API Domains on https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer . After adding that it works with AND without quotes and or a semicolon at the end. try it.. ;)</s> Excuse me. That was all bullcrap. It was one of the two problems.. :)

Comment: As said: the comment above was nonsense. The problem was twofold. I needed to add `http://localhost` to the comma separated list of JavaScript API Domains on linkedin.com/secure/developer AND visit `http://localhost:5000` instead of `127.0.0.1:5000` AND remove the quotes and semicolon.

Comment: @Petr - That is because I also added that domain to the list. Check it out, it doesn't work anymore because I removed the domain and only left localhost in there. And really; I'm not trying to save any points. I just tried to edit your answer to also include the other two points: that I had to add `localhost` to the list of Javascript API Domains, AND that I had to visit `localhost:5000` instead of `127.0.0.1:5000`. If you accept my edit of your answer I'll happily reward you with the 200 points.. :)

Comment: @Petr - Do you really refuse to add the other points about localhost to your answer? If you do so, I can accept your answer and reward you the 200 points. I really don't understand why you became so mad all of a sudden..?

Comment: This one works perfectly for me. In the JavaScript API Domains, I have to include the port , like this : http://localhost:8000 . Thank you Petr!